# Not unique table/alias: 'usertns_group'1066 Please tell me if you spot the error

Tags: sql, mysql, join, mysql-error-1066

The code below looks painstakingly long... but pls if u can spot the error, tell me..

I dont see any duplicates of the alias 'usertns_group' so i wonder why im getting that error..

```
post LEFT JOIN category2 as postcategory2 ON( post.category2_id = postcategory2.category2_id )
 LEFT JOIN category1 as category2category1 ON( postcategory2.category1_id = category2category1.category1_id )
 LEFT JOIN tns_group as category1tns_group ON( category2category1.tns_group_id = category1tns_group.tns_group_id ) 
 LEFT JOIN user as postuser ON( post.user_id = postuser.user_id )
 LEFT JOIN tns_group as usertns_group ON( postuser.tns_group_id = usertns_group.tns_group_id )
 LEFT JOIN status as poststatus ON( post.status_id = poststatus.status_id )
 LEFT JOIN tns_group as posttns_group ON( post.tns_group_id = posttns_group.tns_group_id )
```

thanks..

Comment: I don't recognize "post".  What SQL variant is this?

Answer (score 1):

Maye usertns_group is the name of a column in one of these tables?

Comment: thx for looking.. im sure usertns_group isnt a column name of any table

Comment: Well, then could you please provide the FULL SQL statement?